# Different log locations depending on OS

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, log4j2

I need to store log files in `C:\.DS\logs` in windows and in `/.DS/logs` in Linux.

I found the way to do that: I need to use `System.setProperty("logs.dir", ...)` and use `${logs.dir}` in log4j config file.

Yet, the problem is, log4j is already initialized at this point and it doesn't pick up my system property.

Is there a more straightforward way to do this, whithout me needing to manually re-init log4j?

Thanks

Comment: Answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly) should be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use property lookups in log4j2.xml configuration

Available system properties
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

```
<Properties> //defined in log4j2 config
<Property name="LS">${sys:file.separator}</Property>
<Property name="LOG_DIR">partial_path${LS}partial_path${LS}</Property>
</Properties>
```

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution

then in path to file

```
<RollingFile name="FILE_LOG" fileName="${LOG_DIR}file.log"
```

Comment: That would be incredibly helpful if there was an "if" statement in log4j configs, so I could check ${sys:os.name}.toLower().contains("win") and set my root path to "C:\" or "/". Is there? :)

Comment: Sorry i thought the issue was just the line separator. You could create a default property <Property name="rootPath">/<Property>. If you run your program on windows pass in a parameter on the command line -DrootPath="C:\" it will override the default value if you lookup the value with ${sys:rootPath}. It doesn't avoid the command line argument unfortunately though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140359/xml-conditional-code-in-log4j2-xml according to this post there isn't support for logic in the config :/

Comment: In the end I've decided to store logs in ${user.home}\.DS\logs. I've accepted your answer, but you should probably edit "path.separator" to "file.separator" -- path.separator is ";" on Windows and ":" on Linux

Comment: Questions like this will be better if they asked with examples like "C:\foo\bar", "/var/bar/foo".