# How to append file path conditionally in log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I want to select between two paths for my log file based on an environment variable. If that environment variable exists though, I also want to append few directories to the path returned by that variable.

What I have right now -

```xml
<Properties>
    <Property name="FILE_PATTERN_PREFIX">$${env:ENV_DIR:-.}/output/logs/application-log</Property>
</Properties>
<!-- Use FILE_PATTERN_PREFIX for defining the path -->
```

If `ENV_DIR` exists, this gives me -

```
$ENV_DIR/output/logs/application-log
```

else

```
./output/logs/application-log
```

What I want however is that if `ENV_DIR` exists to get a path like -

```
$ENV_DIR/x/y/z/output/logs/application-log
```

else

```
./output/logs/application-log
```

The `/x/y/z` sub-directories are fixed.

In code my requirement would look something like -

```java
String logPrefix = "";
if(System.getenv("ENV_DIR") != null){
    logPrefix = logPrefix + System.getenv("ENV_DIR") + "/x/y/z";
} else {
    logPrefix = logPrefix + ".";
}
return logPrefix + "/output/logs/application-log";
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with Log4j2 XML config?

Comment: Likely unable to do it solely with xml configuration only. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24160213/16034206 What you could do is inside your application do the check for the environment value, then write the correct log prefix "." or the env/x/y/z as a environment value and have your log4j2 read that environment value.

Comment: Although this works for me on spring boot (I set the env value before running the spring application) you'll need to see the behavior on a regular java application